# Cannot resolve symbol 'DateTimeScheduled' in my linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq query below that can't find 'DateTimeScheduled'

```
var yogaSpace = (from u in context.YogaSpaces
            orderby u.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation)
            where ((u.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation) <= 8047) && (u.Events.DateTimeScheduled >= classDate)) 
            select u).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

DateTimeScheduled is red and intellisense can't find anything inside u.Events almost like it doesn't exist. Intellisnse doesn't see the members inside Events.

Here is my YogaSpace and YogaSpaceEvent objects. I can compile everything fine if I remove the clause "&& (u.Events.DateTimeScheduled >= classDate)", furthermore I have data in my table for this object that I seeded to use for testing!

```
public class YogaSpace
{
    public int YogaSpaceId { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = false)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string ApplicationUserRefId { get; set; }

    public virtual YogaSpaceOverview Overview { get; set; }

    public virtual YogaSpaceDetails Details { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceImage> Images { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ListingComplete ImageCompleted { get; set; }

    public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }

    public virtual YogaSpaceListing Listing { get; set; }

    public virtual YogaSpaceAddress Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceReview> Reviews { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceEvent> Events { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index]
    public YogaSpaceStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 4)]
    public int StepsToList { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserRefId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class YogaSpaceEvent
{
    public int YogaSpaceEventId { get; set; }
    //public string Title { get; set; }
    [Index]
    //research more about clustered indexes to see if it's really needed here
    //[Index(IsClustered = true, IsUnique = false)] 
    public DateTime DateTimeScheduled { get; set; }
    public int AppointmentLength { get; set; }
    public int StatusEnum { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int YogaSpaceRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("YogaSpaceRefId")]
    public virtual YogaSpace YogaSpace { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property `u.Events` is a collection of events.  Therefore it cannot have a single value for `DateTimeScheduled`, it has multiple values.

You need to select events that have `DateTimeScheduled >= classDate` first.  Something like this:

```
var yogaSpace = (from u in context.YogaSpaces
        orderby u.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation)
        where ((u.Address.LocationPoints.Distance(myLocation) <= 8047) 
        && (u.Events.Any(e => e.DateTimeScheduled >= classDate))) 
        select u).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

The changed portion of the code `u.Events.Any(e => e.DateTimeScheduled >= classDate)` will now return a boolean true or false that indicates if any of the events are scheduled on or after the class date.